# Timba not showing survey when partner user logged in

Tags: sharing, partner-communities

We are using Timba surveys and have followed the site setup guide. The survey shows up fine when not logged into the community. However, once a user logs in, they no longer have access to the survey. When trying to apply the same permissions to the partner user as the Guest user profile, Salesforce throws an error that partner users cannot have "View All" or "Modify All" access.

I've enabled super user access, enables the external sharing model and done everything I can think of to give these users permissions, but it gives the same error.

Inside of Timba, I see that they have a "Surveys" tab that they say is specifically for Partner Communities. However, no surveys appear on this tab in the community and I cannot find any documentation stating how it is intended to work.

Has anyone been able to get Timba working with Partner communities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Altimetrik, only portals are supported, not communities. For communities SurveyForce may be the better option